# Asp.Net MVC Razor FileUpload Html Helper into existing View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor, html-helper

I have have a View where I add products to a simple WebStore. I want to have multiple images with one product. That's why I use FileUpload from Microsoft.Web.Helpers. The use of FileUpload in my View is like this:

```
@FileUpload.GetHtml("Upload", 5, true, true, addText: "Add more", uploadText: "Upload files")
```

Then I have some labels and fields for other product attributs like this:

```
<div class="editor-field"><br>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)<br>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)<br>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I use post method, my controller does not get anything. I use controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload)
{
    foreach (var file in fileUpload)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

So does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong. Because my FileUpload object is always empty.

Answer (score 14):

Most likely your `BeginForm` is missing the required field. It should look like this:

```
using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
    new { enctype="multipart/form-data" })) { 

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Now using **`HttpPostedFileBase`** in mvc 4 easy to upload multiple files, [EditorFor FileUpload in asp.net mvc 4 razor](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-create-and-editorfor-fileupload.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last night `FileUpload` control and the parameter name should be the same

Change:

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> **fileUpload**)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> **upload**)
```